# NodeJS Stream badly returned via async/await

Tags: node.js, stream, async-await

I am trying to check if an image exists in a folder.
If it exists I want to pipe its stream to res (I'm using Express)
If it does not exist I want to do another thing.

I created an async function that is supposed to either return the image's stream if it exists or false if it doesn't.

I get a stream when I do it but I get an infinite load on the browser, as if there was an issue with the stream.

Here is the minimal reproduction I could have :
[Link to runnable code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jCS0hgTPDUrfaDczn2_8HAYjBFH5yx2/view?usp=sharing)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Check if the image is already converted by returning a stream or false
    const ext = 'jpg';
    const imageConvertedStream = await imageAlreadyConverted(
        './foo',
        1,
        '100x100',
        80,
        ext
    );

    // Image already converted, we send it back
    if (imageConvertedStream) {
        console.log('image exists');

        res.type(`image/${ext}`);

        imageConvertedStream.pipe(res);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('Image not found');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

async function imageAlreadyConverted(
    basePath,
    id,
    size,
    quality,
    extWanted
) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // If we know the wanted extension, we check if it exists
        let imagePath;

        if (extWanted) {
            imagePath = path.join(
                basePath,
                size,
                `img_${id}_${quality}.${extWanted}`
            );
        } else {
            imagePath = path.join(basePath, size, `img_${id}_${quality}.jpg`);
        }

    console.log(imagePath);

        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(imagePath);

        readStream.on('error', () => {
      console.log('error');
            resolve(false);
        });

        readStream.on('readable', () => {
      console.log('readable');
            resolve(readStream);
        });
    });
}
```

95% of my images will be available and I need performance, I suppose checking with fs.stats and then creating the stream is taking longer than trying to create the stream and handling the error.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please post the entire code that is necessary to replicate the problem - a repo, etc. It seems that you don't handle errors in async function, and an error will result in pending request, but this isn't known for sure since you didn't provide all the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question with a mvce. I tried posting it on repl.it but it seems it doesn't allow streams, so I gave a google doc zip.

Comment: All necessary code should be presented in the question itself, in your case it's index.js. It has something to do with 'readable' event, I don't use it myself. You can omit Express, async/await and everything else to replicate it. I suppose this can be done with something like `imageConvertedStream.pipe(fileOutputStream)`. You can check that readStream.bytesRead is non-zero when there's `readable` listener and is zero when there's none. Seems like the stream was already read this way, there's nothing to pipe to `res`. I'd suggest to ask a new question which is more specific to streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the "readable" event. Once I switched to the "open" event, everything is fine.